# Instrument-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm curious what people think of having tags for every instrument vs a generic `instrumental` tag.

Comment: *every* instrument? That's a lot of tags!

Comment: Let's not get every type of clarinet or French Horn into a tag. There are more than you can imagine...

Comment: @PelletenCate: This question is about how instrumental questions should be tagged, I'm sure that `instrumental` is related to the core of this meta question. If we focus to disallow tags of the site here we're going to have a bad performing search function and undertagged questions, because there will be a lot of `discussion` about `tags` in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a good idea. I would also extend this to include all major types of audio equipment as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for that. Each instrument is unique when it comes to reproducing its sound faithfully.

Answer (score 3):

For sure. There ought to be a "vocals" tag, and vocals is "just" another instrument after all. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The more I think about it the more I like the idea of instrument-specific tags.  I can see myself searching for mic questions within a guitar tag for example.

Answer (score 2):

+1, it's a good idea

Answer (score 2):

How about instrument families instead?

In a recording context there tend to be parallels between different forms of the same instrument. In the more mainstream stuff (Bass, Guuitar etc.) each instrument has a very specific set of rules/guidelines for how to record it (DI the bass, mic the guitar, etc.), and the same for the more esoteric instruments that don't really have parallels.

But Alto Saxophone vs Tenor Saxophone? Cello vs. Double Bass (bowed, not jazz-style)?

Perhaps we would be best with *some* specific tags, but mostly just tags like "bowed-strings", "horns", "brass"?

Comment: c'mon folks, don't downvote without saying why

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer, votes on the meta are often used to show (dis)agreement with what someone wrote. For that reason anything that happens on the meta doesn't have any effect towards your reputation...

Comment: oh right, sorry, this is my first time using the meta sites, I'm too used to the QA bits.

Comment: This sounds like an extremely sensible idea to me. I think in the early days we should be generous and allow a lot of tags, then merge or delete ones that don't come up very often.

Answer (score 2):

Agree, This would be a good idea. I'm a member over at MPC-Forums.com where the members who go there only care about AKAI MPC products. Its a very very active community and being able to filter searches or results on Brand and product through tags/etc would be a great value add.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering and searching purposes, I agree with this idea so it can be more specific.

I would propose to only use the `instrumental` tag when we are talking about them in general...